# How to sort number in the form of 00-00?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to sort rows by the number of falts & rooms:

```
1-1 (flat1 room 1)
11-1 (flat 11 room1)
11-8
12-5
13-1
2
5-5
```

When sorting these rows in an ascending order, it always give wrong order even if I add 0 before every single digit

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D6q7IsdAIIgD-9GuMNSdLhBVDOtKniDW_cy-Td0Sq_I/edit#gid=1162496797

I tried to make a helper column by adding `=arrayformula(text(B1:B,"00"))`
Also tried to add 0 in front of every number by `=arrayformula(0&B5:B)`. But all didn't work

Comment: Please show what you tried directly in the question body and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I got it `=iferror(ArrayFormula(IFs(REGEXMATCH(B4:B, "-"), SUBSTITUTE(B4:B,"-",""), B4:B<>0,B4:B*10,B4:B=0,0)))` but when I query these data from other sheet , it results in most numbers of zeros!!. see test sheet

Comment: @HassanAlmaateeq. What exactly is it you are trying to do? And which part is the room number? The `12` part, the `5` part or the `12-5` part. Also please share a greater set of data WITH the expected results.

Comment: Column B is the room number formatted as flat number-room number. Column D is the arrayformula that removed "-" and multiplies single digit with 10 to make the number easily sorted . Then Column F is using query function to brings these data in other tabs but I put it in the same tab for simplicity. I noticed the numbers are not shown all.

Comment: Please share the **expected result** and place it in column C

Comment: =iferror(ArrayFormula(IFs(REGEXMATCH(B4:B, "-"), SUBSTITUTE(B4:B,"-",""), B4:B<>"-",B4:B*10))) This formula will correct the flat and room number in tens. Then in Column D (D4) =query(B4:C,"select B,C where B is not null AND B<>'Room' order by C ASC",0) This query function will be placed in different tab but for simplicity, I put it here. I noticed the numbers are still not sorted by order of column C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=ArrayFormula(text(ArrayFormula(IFs(REGEXMATCH(O5:O, "-"), SUBSTITUTE(O5:O,"-",""), O5:O<>"-",O5:O*10)),"00000"))`

That solved the issue and sorted the rooms perfectly